# Appcelerator Errors When Running Android

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, hyperloop

I'm having issues when trying to run the Android Emulator with Appcelerator. I'm new to this program and not having much luck finding an answer on how to fix this error. My app development knowledge up til now is Xcode and Apache Cordova. I've uninstalled/reinstalled Appcelerator along with different versions of Node with no luck. iPhone runs fine, so I'm guessing it's something with Java, but I can't figure out how or where to find it or fix it.
I'm running Appcelerator v7.1.2 with Node v8.16.0 and npm v6.4.1. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Below is what it is showing when I try to run for Android.

```
[INFO] :   Deploy type: development
[INFO] :   Building for target: emulator
[INFO] :   Building for emulator: Pixel_2_XL_API_29
[INFO] :   Targeting Android SDK API: 29
[INFO] :   Building for the following architectures: arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86
[INFO] :   Signing with keystore: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/8.3.0.GA/android/dev_keystore (tidev)
[INFO] :   Debugging disabled
[INFO] :   Profiler disabled
[INFO] :   Transpile javascript: true
[INFO] :   Generate source maps: true
[INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: /Users/user/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/MyFirstApp/build/android/build-manifest.json does not exist
[INFO] :   Starting Hyperloop assembly
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating system metabase
**[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] :  hyperloop:generateMetabase: Failed to generated metabase: warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 6
error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] :  An error occurred during build after 735ms
[ERROR] :  warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 6
[ERROR] :  error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] :  error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.**
```

Comment: can you please show us the version output of `appc info`. For node try to use v10.13.x. And you have to use Java 1.8

Comment: any solutions @miga?

Comment: the author didn't reply to my comment so I can't help

Comment: @miga I am having same issue. You can view my appc info at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e_MzgsLhBV1cF8jEWzYSvmCpSBhL4nzw/view?usp=sharing   You may need to download and open with editor

Comment: @Sanman please read the first comment: you have java 13.0.1_9 and node 12. Especially the Java version is not supported (node might work). But you have to use java 1.8 as mentioned earlier

Answer (score 1):

As a different user has the same question and provided additional information it is likely that it is the same issue:

- use Java 1.8
- use Node 10.13.x

especially the Java version is required. Node might work in a newer version but the official supported version is 10.13.x at the moment

Comment: Setting up java fixed my issue. I didn't touch the node. Thanks :)